# I try to ge the sum of 2 values using + but It does not work

Tags: jquery

How come I dont get the sum of **ytpris** and **grundpris** doing like I did?
Instead I get the both values beside each other in the input of totalsumma

It works this way using *, but not + ... why?

```
$('#totalsumma').val($('#ytpris').val() + $('#grundpris').val());
```

Comment: .val() returns string, you need to parse it to number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse it to a number

```
$('#totalsumma').val(parseFloat($('#ytpris').val()) + parseFloat($('#grundpris').val()));
```

Multiply converts strings to numbers automatically, thats why * works. Using + adds strings together if they are strings

Answer (score 0):

$('#ytpris').val() returns string, and "+" just concatinating it;
Use parseFloat($('#ytpris').val())

Answer (score 0):

if expecting integer.

```
$('#totalsumma').val(parseInt($('#ytpris').val(),10) + parseInt($('#grundpris').val(),10));
```

If expecting float values replace

> parseInt

by

> parseFloat

and remove base "10"